# How do I approve & publish a folder and everything inside it?

Tags: 2010, publishing

How do I approve & publish a folder so that everything inside of it is published and live?

**Please post a screencast**

Comment: Is this a coding or UI question?

Comment: This is a UI question

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Manage Content and Structure function in SharePoint (from site settings on all publishing sites) to select everything in a folder (mark all items in heading row) and publish it.

Comment: What does *mark all items in heading column* mean?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I meant the title (heading) row in the top of the grid being displayed. There is a check-box and when you select it all currently viewed items are being selected.

Comment: but that doesn't answer my question at all..

Comment: I mean the main question up above..

Comment: I understand your question in this way: You want to publish all items within a folder in a document library in an easy way. My reply to that is that you choose 'Manage Content and Structure' from site settings, click on the document library, click on the folder within the document library, select all the items in that folder (by clicking on the check-box in the title row) and than publish the items.

Comment: Not within a folder.. recursive, cascading thru all nested folders..

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is possible in 2010: Create a flat view (under folders) for the library with not item limit, select all items in the view (heading row check-box) and choose publish in the ribbon. The ribbon will not show if you have more than one list view on the page.

Answer (score 3):

If you have SharePoint 2010 standard license you will get document sets.  Document sets allow you to treat documents as one set.  Similar to a folder.  Whats nice about sets is you can than use a approval workflow to approve the complete set.

If you want to continue to use existing folders a workflow to approve all docs will be difficult.  Perhaps others have ideas.

Comment: How do I find a set? or create a set? It is 2010.

Comment: Document Sets are content types - provided the feature is enabled on your site, you should be able to add it as a content type to your list, and then create an item of type "Document Set".

Comment: Can you please post a screencast? I'm still quite confused..

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-document-sets-HA101782466.aspx and be sure to check links under See Also (right side of page)

Comment: Is this a good idea? Document sets are supposed to be logical groupings of documents. OP is looking to approve all items in a folder, and all the items in that folder need not be related.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually run workflows against a folder, so you could create a custom workflow in Visual Studio and maybe even SPD with some help (...i.e. you'd probably need some 3rd party activities) to go iterate through the items in the folder the workflow was initiated against and approve/publish the files within it.  Once deployed, you'd simply go to the ECB (context menu) for the folder and click Workflows or select the folder and click the Workflows button on the Ribbon.

Short of the Document Set idea put forth by Paul, I can't think of a no/low-code way to do this...and The document set approach is going to require a fair amount of work if you have a lot of existing content that would need to be moved from folders into document sets.